# When retrieving data from a public S3 bucket, is it preferable to use the SDK or download the XML file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am working with a public AWS S3 bucket from which I only need to retrieve data. The bucket permissions only allow data retrieval, and no other operations are permitted.

I have experimented with two approaches to access the data:

1. **Downloading the XML**: I programmatically downloaded the XML representation of the bucket's contents. Afterward, I parsed this XML to identify and download the specific files I needed from the bucket.
2. **Using the SDK**: I created a client using the AWS SDK. This allowed me to directly fetch objects from the bucket without having to deal with the intermediary step of parsing XML files.

While I observed that the SDK approach eliminated the need for XML parsing, I didn’t notice any other distinct advantages. Are there other benefits to using the SDK, or is the XML method just as efficient? I'd appreciate any insights or best practices on this matter. My main expectation was to identify a method that is both efficient and commonly accepted as a standard practice in the AWS community.

Comment: What XML are you talking about? Generally for public buckets it is enough to just hit the url with the object and be done with it, no need for the SDK. For anything else, particularly involving authentication, you should use the SDK.

Comment: I am creating a program to download all objects from the bucket so I thought need to parse XML with the contents of the bucket provided to get valid URLs to downloaded the objects.

Comment: Okay, you are talking about *listing* first and then retrieving all the files, I get it. Now back to your question: *"Are there other benefits to using the SDK, or is the XML method just as efficient?"* - the bare XML approach is probably more *efficient* than using the SDK in terms of actual computation but it is way more complex for you to implement and maintain and requires knowledge over the fact that there is XML going on, what structure that XML has, how to parse it, etc. The purpose of the SDK is abstraction so that you do not have to deal with all of that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the AWS SDK for Java, make sure you use V2 over V1. V1 is no [longer recommended](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples#aws-sdk-code-examples).

To learn the advanages of using the *AWS SDK for Java V2*, I recommend you look at the Java V2 Developer Guide.

[Developer Guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

A few benefits are:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at runtime.***

If for example, you need to interact with AWS Services using Asynchronous programming, this is fully supported with V2:

[Asynchronous programming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html)

There are many other benfits too as opposed to writing your own logic and using XML.